# Collect array of tuples from for loop

Tags: julia

I have some code that does a calculation using a `@parallel for` loop, producing a tuple of output at each iteration. I want to collect these tuples in an array for further processing:

```
n=2
out = @sync @parallel (hcat) for i=1:n
    (i, i+1)
end
for i=1:n
    (j,k) = out[i]
    # do something
end
println("okay")
```

If here is only one iteration of the loop, `out` is a tuple, rather than an array of tuples, and `(j,k) = out[i]` throws an error.

```
n=1
out = @sync @parallel (hcat) for i=1:n
    (i, i+1)
end
for i=1:n
    (j,k) = out[i] # error
    # do something
end
println("not reached")
```

Is there a way I can force `out` to be an array of tuples regardless of the value of `n`, without having to do any checks on `out` after the loop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `hcat` on `Tuple...`, you will be guided to a more general algorithm :

```
julia> @which hcat((1,2))
hcat{T}(X::T...) at abstractarray.jl:710

julia> @which hcat([(1,2)])
hcat{T}(V::Array{T,1}...) at array.jl:690
```

and it takes more time for Julia to do `hcat` :

```
julia> @time out = @sync @parallel (hcat) for i=1:10_000
           (i, i+1)
       end;
0.146527 seconds (4.67 k allocations: 508.905 KB)

julia> @time out = @sync @parallel (hcat) for i=1:10_000
           [(i, i+1)]
       end;
0.061976 seconds (4.76 k allocations: 513.370 KB)
```

also, if you use second syntax you, do not get an error when `n=1`:

```
n=1
out = @sync @parallel (hcat) for i=1:n
    [(i, i+1)]
end
for i=1:n
    (j,k) = out[i] # OK
    # do something
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `hcat(hcat(x)) = hcat(x)` but is always a Matrix. You could add:

```
out = hcat(out)
```

after the parallel loop. But this seems like a hack.

Comment: @Reza's answer: replace `(i,i+1)` with `[(i,i+1)]` looks better. In any case parallel looping over 1 element one should expect some overhead.